# 'Linked Server Properties' different per user?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I received a ticket that someone of the BI team could not make use of a linked server. He got the `"Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'"-ERROR` and sent me the query.

I ran the query and it ran just fine from the same exact SQL instance. I took over his machine and noticed that when I checked the Security settings in the `Linked Server Properties` on the SQL instance they are set to "**Not be made**" and could not be changed...

I check the same settings under my user and there they are set to the correct setting "**Be made using the login's current security context**".

Do the settings need to be set for every user? If so, how?

EDIT:

For the doubters

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Those settings are server level, not user (actually `LOGIN`). To make a "silly" statment, but you might to check you  *were* looking at the same object

Comment: When you ran the query, were you logged in directly to the SQL Server?  If so it might be a Kerberos double-hop issue.

Comment: @Larnu I have added screenshots to show you it's the same object.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft The double-hop is user independent is it not? It should fail for every user.